# Converting RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am relatively new to Spark and Scala.

I am starting with the following dataframe (single column made out of a dense Vector of Doubles):

```
scala> val scaledDataOnly_pruned = scaledDataOnly.select("features")
scaledDataOnly_pruned: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector]

scala> scaledDataOnly_pruned.show(5)
+--------------------+
|            features|
+--------------------+
|[-0.0948337274182...|
|[-0.0948337274182...|
|[-0.0948337274182...|
|[-0.0948337274182...|
|[-0.0948337274182...|
+--------------------+
```

A straight conversion to RDD yields an instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] :

```
scala> val scaledDataOnly_rdd = scaledDataOnly_pruned.rdd
scaledDataOnly_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[32] at rdd at <console>:66
```

Does anyone know how to convert this DF to an instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] instead? My various attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 7):

Just found out:

```
val scaledDataOnly_rdd = scaledDataOnly_pruned.map{x:Row => x.getAs[Vector](0)}
```

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: use more sophisticated way to interpret fields in Row.

This is worked for me

```
val featureVectors = features.map(row => {
  Vectors.dense(row.toSeq.toArray.map({
    case s: String => s.toDouble
    case l: Long => l.toDouble
    case _ => 0.0
  }))
})
```

features is a DataFrame of spark SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

scaledDataOnly
   .rdd
   .map{
      row => Vectors.dense(row.getAs[Seq[Double]]("features").toArray)
     }
```