# How to convert RDD[Row] to RDD[Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to implement k-means method using scala.
I created a RDD something like that

```
val df = sc.parallelize(data).groupByKey().collect().map((chunk)=> {
  sc.parallelize(chunk._2.toSeq).toDF()
})

val examples = df.map(dataframe =>{
  dataframe.selectExpr(
    "avg(time) as avg_time",
    "variance(size) as var_size",
    "variance(time) as var_time",
    "count(size) as examples"
  ).rdd
})

val rdd_final=examples.reduce(_ union _)

val kmeans= new KMeans()
val model = kmeans.run(rdd_final)
```

With this code I obtain an error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
[error]  required:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
```

So I tried to cast doing:

```
val rdd_final_Vector = rdd_final.map{x:Row => x.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector](0)}

val model = kmeans.run(rdd_final_Vector)
```

But then I obtain an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

So I'm looking for a way to do that cast, but I can't find any method.

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915327/2661491

Comment: Yes, I've read but don't understand. I see errors with "dense" and "getAs". I changed the val rdd_final_Vector to:


    val rdd_final_Vector= rdd_final.map{
        row => Vectors.dense(row.getAs[Seq[Double]].toArray) }

but I obtaining errors :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least a couple of issues here:

1. *No* you really can not cast a Row to a Vector: a Row is a collection of potentially disparate types understood by `Spark SQL`. A `Vector` is not a native spark sql type
2. There seems to be a mismatch between the content of your SQL statement and what you are attempting to achieve with `KMeans`:  the SQL is performing aggregations. But `KMeans` expects a series of individual data points in the form a Vector (which encapsulates an `Array[Double]`) .  So then - why are you supplying `sum`'s and `average`'s to a `KMeans` operation?

Addressing just #1 here:  you will need to do something along the lines of:

```
val doubVals = <rows rdd>.map{ row =>   row.getDouble("colname") }
val vector = Vectors.toDense{ doubVals.collect}
```

Then you have a properly encapsulated `Array[Double]` (within a Vector) that can be supplied to `Kmeans`.

Comment: Thanks javadba. I'll review my code.
I'm supplying sum's and average's because I get streaming data and I'm trying to create an object with the data's average and data's sum every n seconds: that object I'll supply yo KMeans.

Comment: Gives me classnotfound exception

Comment: @Amalo . You have a completely different issue: the `Vectors` class is a core `Spark` mllib component.