# Convert a RDD[(Long,Long)] to RDD[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tuples

How do I convert a RDD[(Long, Long)] to RDD[Row]?

I require the RDD[Row] to convert to a DataFrame. The closest I got to an answer is 
 [How to convert RDD[Row] to RDD[Vector]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488722/how-to-convert-rddrow-to-rddvector) but I want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply schema to your RDD (ref: [spark-sql-programming-guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html))

```
case class MyObjectType(col1:Long, col2:Long)

val myRDD:RDD[Long, Long] = .........
val myDF = myRDD.map(r=>MyObjectType(r._1, r._2)).toDF
```

now if you want to run sql over this df, you can register it as temp table

```
myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I wanted it to do. Just to be clear the case class is used to create the schema of the DF?

Comment: case class defines the schema of the table. The names of the arguments to the case class are read using reflection and become the names of the columns.